# Windows 7 Professional: always forgets shared directory on truecrypt volume

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares

I mount my true crypt volume with a logon script, so it is available very early after logging in. Then I right-click the directory, Properties -> Sharing -> Advanced Sharing -> UAC: Yes ->  [x] Share this folder -> Permissions -> Everyone: Full Control -> OK -> OK -> Close. The last steps I have to repeat after each reboot.

Is there a Windows option which I have to set, so it will remember the network share? Or can I execute the above procedure in a script which I can add to the autostart folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this be of use? It's for use under Vista so should work with 7

> 1. Create a folder on your ordinary hard disc, “Shared”.
> 2. Go into “Shared”, from a command prompt (Start->Run->cmd)
> 3. Type “junction “Stuff” F:\My_Removable_Drive”
>
> That creates a symlink called “Stuff”
>   under “Shared”, which will point to
>   F:\My_Removable_Drive
>
> You can now share the folder “Shared”
>   and have network access to your
>   Removable drives whenever they’re
>   plugged in, without having to
>   tediously recreate the share every
>   time.

Taken from [here](http://parallaxed.net/article/share-removable-devices)

Comment: Instead of `junction` from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) one also can use `mklink /j <link> <target>`.